# Kafka slow join

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am running confluent-oss-5.0.0-2.11 kafka server with default server properties (from etc/kafka) on my local PC and created topics test1 and test2 with the below command

```
kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 –topic
```

Below are the environment properties I have

```
props.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 10);
props.put(BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 16384);
props.put(LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 10);
props.put(BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, 33554432);
props.put(METADATA_MAX_AGE_CONFIG, "10");
```

Here is what the producer does

```
String padded = RandomStringUtils.random(2000, true, true);
for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++) {
    kafkaProducer.send("a" + i, "aa" + padded + i, "test1");
    kafkaProducer.send("a" + i, "bb" + padded + i, "test2");
}
kafkaProducer.flush();
```

Here is what the consumer does

```
KTable<String, String> a = builder.table("test");

KTable<String, String> b = builder.table("test1");

a.join(b, new ValueJoiner<String, String, String>() {

    @Override

    public String apply(String value1, String value2) {

        return "a" + value1;

    }

}).toStream().to("finalTopic");
```

And below is how I observe the performance of "finalTopic" population

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
builder.<String, String>stream("finalTopic").peek((key, value) -> {
    if(counter.incrementAndGet()%1000 == 0) {
        logger.info("date {}, final join key {}, value size {}, joins performed {}", System.currentTimeMillis(), key, value.length(), counter.get());
    }
});
```

I managed to get around **55,000 messages per second** getting above messages into different Kafka topics using producer.

However, on the consumer side, the rate of messages are being populated into "finalTopic" is at around **110 messages per second**.

Any pointer is appreciated!

Comment: I guess the question is, if your application is lagging? Did you check the consumer lag? Next question is: how many records do actually join? Maybe your result is just small.

Comment: if you read my example, all messages of two topics are using the same keys. So every record joins.

Comment: I missed this. I assume you verified that that the result is correct and complete? How do you measure performance? Also, what do you exactly mean with "consumer side" -- the Kafka Streams application? Or a downstream consumer that reads "finalTopic"?

Comment: updated with how I observe the performance, basically "peek" the "finalTopic" stream and print timestamp for every 1000 messages.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax any thoughts are really appreciated. We are also trying KSql to see if that helps.

Comment: So you are getting a log statement about each 10 seconds? I am wondering if it's related to KTable caches -- try to set cache size to zero in the config.